# Choosing how many list's elements to print before going to new line

Tags: python, list

I didn't know how to set up a proper title so I will try my best to explain my problem.
I have a list with an undefined number of items (so it could be 3 or 3000). I want to print 4 items on the same line and after the 4th item go to the next line, then repeat the process until the items finish.
I tried something like this:

```
for x in range(len(stuff)):
    counter = 0
    if counter == 4:
        print("\n")
        counter = 0
    else:
        print(stuff[x].text, end="")
        counter +=1
```

but it still prints everything on the same line.
Any ideas?

Comment: The main issue with your code it the first `counter = 0` should be before the loop. Also, the `else` shouldn't be there - you want to execute `print(...)` _every_ iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close! The biggest problem is simply that you're initializing `counter` to `0` at the start of every iteration. Try moving the variable initialization to outside the loop:

```py
counter = 0
for x in range(len(stuff)):
    if counter == 4:
        print("\n")
        counter = 0
    else:
        print(stuff[x].text, end="")
        counter +=1
```

Note also that `print("\n")` may be printing more newlines than you intend. If you simply want to end the line and move to a new one without adding an extra blank line in between, you can just do `print("")`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was such a stupid mistake... Thanks!

Comment: This results in an error. `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` at `print(l[x].text, end="")`

Comment: Haha, "stupid" mistakes are a programmer's bread and butter. Happy I could help!

Comment: If you *know* that you are using Python 3, I tend to prefer `print()` to `print("")` - although `print("")` has the advantage that it will also do the same thing in Python 2. In this case, the use of `end=""` shows that it is indeed Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

```
for x in range(0,len(stuff),4):
    print(stuff[x:x+4],sep = '')
```

should work